# Basic question about probability of inherited genes

Tags: probability

This question comes from [this problem](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=663) at ACM ICPC live archive (programming contest archive).

The problem gives you a monster family tree. If monster A has monsters B and C as parents, than each of its genes has probability of 50% of being the same gene from B and 50% of being the same gene from C. Some monsters have no parents, these monsters don't inherit their genes from anyone (and each parentless monster have different genes from each other).

Given the family tree of the monsters, the problem asks you to tell the expected percentage of common genes between a pair of monsters M1 and M2. (Please read the problem statement for further clarifications, in case I got something wrong).
The problem is that I could not understand the test case given with the problem. 

Here's a picture of the family tree of the test case in order to make it easy to visualize:
[image: Monster Family Tree]

Now, these are the gene probabilities according to my understanding of the problem:
((mosnter) gene: chance).

(1) 1: 100%
(2) 2: 100%
(3) 3: 100%
(4) 1: 50%, 2: 50%
(5) 2: 50%, 3: 50%
(6) 4: 50%, 5: 50% -> 1: 25%, 2: 50%, 3: 25%
(7) 6: 50%, 5: 50% -> 1: 12.5%, 2: 50%, 3: 37.5%

On the examples, it asks for the expected probability for monsters 7 and 5 to have the same genes.
For me it is:
P(7 have gene 1)*P(5 have gene 1) + P(7 have gene 2)*P(5 have gene 2) + P(7 have gene 3)*P(5 have gene 3) =
0.125*0 + 0.5*0.5 + 0.375*0.5 = 0.4375 = 43.75%
But the answer for this query (according to the problem description) is 81.25%

Could somebody help me figure out what am I getting wrong?
A friend helped me understand the "81.25%" in a easier way. But I want to understand what is wrong with my reasoning (reducing the genes to the "initial" ones and then comparing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure generates the probabilities that each monster inherits a particular gene. But those probabilities are not independent: if monster 5 inherits gene number 2, for example, then monster 7 has a different chance of inheriting gene 2. You should use the conditional probability formula:
$$
\Pr (\text{Monster 5 has gene 2 and Monster 7 has gene 2} ) = \Pr(\text{Monster 7 has gene 2 | Monster 5 has gene 2}
) \Pr(\text{Monster 5 has gene 2})$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand how it should be done. Should I use the conditional prob while calculating the probabilities of the "initial genes" for each one(as I did for 1 to 7), or should I do it only at the end (while calculating the similarity). 
Could you provide me an example?